# Using Selenium VBA: How to access a Chrome window that was opened by another app?

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome

I work with Excel VBA Selenium under Windows 10.
I want to access a Chrome window that has previously been opened by another app and of whose name only the first part is known, the rest is a code that changes each time it is created. It is open together with other tabs in the active Chrome browser.

In order to start Chrome with Selenium, all I know to do is

```
Set dr = New ChromeDriver
```

This creates an Object "dr". When I look up the properties of dr, the property "Windows" shows the value
"BrowserNotStartedError / Browser not started. Call Get, Start or StartRemotely first."

Start or get both create a new Chrome instance which does not allow me to access windows in the already open instance.
I tried to use this code without "New", but this does not work.
I have not found any hint on how to work on the **existing** instance of Chrome. Is it possible at all?
If not, how else could I access any existing window? The URL is unique and can only be created by the 3rd party app for security reasons. If I try to copy the URL to the new Chrome instance I get an authentication error, so this is not an option.
This web page basically contains a menu that allows me to download certain data safely, which I want to automate.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't do this. Use shell/internet explorer to grab a handle on existing IE window (no good if app only chrome based). See whether you can launch a  saved chrome profile that includes the app from selenium that might give control to selenium - works with some extensions for example but those are browser extensions. Not sure what kind of app you are using.

Comment: Thank you @QHarr. The app is a brokerage app. Good to know that I cannot do it with Selenium, so I won't waste more time on it and can explore other solutions. Chrome is my default browser and I don't want to change it, so this page is always created with Chrome.

Comment: The page I wanted to work on has the advantage that I am already logged in when it's created by the app, but I can also get there by logging in to a log-in page newly created with Selenium. It just requires some more manual steps, but resolves the problem.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question has been resolved.
With a Selenium driver for Chrome, it is not possible to access Chrome tabs that have not been created with Selenium.
According to [QHarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6241235/qharr), it could be done by using shell/internet explorer to grab a handle on existing IE windows. In this case, of course, the app would have to create the HTML file with IE, i.e. the default browser would have to be IE.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a way to do it with Selenium driver for Chrome.
Locate your chrome.exe directory and copy and append the line below into the target bar.

--remote-debugging-port=9222 (Include the preceding space).

Then copy the following code into a vba module, execute it, and it will allow you to manipulate the existing chrome session that you created.

```
Dim chromeBrowser As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Sub existingChromeSession()
      Set chromeBrowser = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
      chromeBrowser.SetCapability "debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222"
      chromebrowser.Get("https://www.google.com")
End Sub
```