# VBA Seleniunbasic - Codes in different Modules

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, automation

I’m using Seleniumbasic for sessions automation throught VBA, where I do have a module1 with my Login code :

```
    Private ChromoLink As New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Login()
 
   ‘LOGIN 
    With ChromoLink
       .Start "Chrome"
        ChromoLink.Window.Maximize
        .get "https://......"
        While ChromoLink.ExecuteScript("return document.readyState") <> "complete"
        ChromoLink.Wait (5000)
        Wend
        .FindElementById("i0116").SendKeys User
        .FindElementById("i0118").SendKeys Password
        .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""idSIButton9""]").Click
    
   End With
  
End Sub
```

After I do my login. In module2 when I try to run my code it’s not working, here is my code:

```
    'GO TO ANOTHER TAB AND NAVIGATE TO ANOTHER LINK ADDRESS: 
     ChromoLink.ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", "https://..."
                    ChromoLink.SwitchToNextWindow
    While ChromoLink.ExecuteScript("return document.readyState") <> "complete"
    ChromoLink.Wait (5000)
    Wend
```

And here is the error msg :

[image]]

Comment: I am guessing that what you are trying to do is attach to a browser session that has already started - AFAIK this is not supported in VBA.

Comment: Read this answer however ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64236384/using-selenium-vba-how-to-access-a-chrome-window-that-was-opened-by-another-app